# PHP/SQL creating links to next row in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Lets say i have a databse:

```
+----------+
| Database |
+----------+
| id       |
| image    |
| category |
+----------+
```

Now i have a page that shows an image from the database, i want to add a

> << Previous image

and

> Next image >>

button. I could just take the $id and add +1 , but what if the next ID does not exist in the DB ?

Any help appreciated, thanks

So i found this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM database AS c 
 WHERE (id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM database WHERE id < c.id AND language = 'en')
    OR  id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM database WHERE id > c.id AND language = 'en'))
```

But how do i make a link out of it, like:
`<a href="domain.com/$c ??">Next</a>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use another select:

```sql
SELECT
    ( SELECT ID FROM <TABLE-NAME> WHERE ID > $currentID ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1 )
    AS NEXT_VALUE,
    ( SELECT ID FROM <TABLE-NAME> WHERE ID < $currentID ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1 )
    AS PREV_VALUE
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Just edited my question, will you take a look at the code i found ? Thanks

Comment: 2by That really is a second question

Comment: No, but it is difficult to make the answers to your original question fit a new question.

Comment: Should i make a new question ?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001648/getting-row-before-and-after-a-query), you can use a subselect query to get the ID of the previous and next records:

```
...
WHERE id IN (
  '$id',
  (SELECT MAX(id) FROM yourTable WHERE id < '$id'),
  (SELECT MIN(id) FROM yourTable WHERE id > '$id')
)
...
```

Comment: How to use this? :) I dont understand the other answer, sorry