# SELECT N rows before and after the row matching the condition?

Tags: mysql

The behaviour I want to replicate is like grep with `-A` and `-B` flags .
eg `grep -A 2 -B 2 "hello" myfile.txt` will give me all the lines which have "hello" in them, but also 2 lines before and 2 lines after it.
Lets assume this table schema :

```
+--------+-------------------------+
| id     |    message              |
+--------+-------------------------+
| 1      | One tow three           |
| 2      | No error in this        |
| 3      | My testing message      |
| 4      | php module test         |
| 5      | hello world             |
| 6      | team spirit             |
| 7      | puzzle game             |
| 8      | social game             |
| 9      | stackoverflow           |
|10      | stackexchange           |
+------------+---------------------+
```

Now a query like :
`Select * from theTable where message like '%hello%'` will result in :

`5      | hello world`

How can I put another parameter "N" which selects N rows before, and N rows after the matched record i.e. for N = 2, the result should be  :

```
    | 3      | My testing message      |
    | 4      | php module test         |
    | 5      | hello world             |
    | 6      | team spirit             |
    | 7      | puzzle game             |
```

- For simplicity assume 'like %TERM%' matches only 1 row .
- Here the result is supposed to be sorted on auto-increment `id` field.

Comment: at least specify an ordering..

Comment: hi yi_H, its specified as last point in the question

Comment: will your first statement/query always only return one row? or can it return multiple rows as well?

Comment: @DaanTimmer that is also specified as second last point in the question :( Please read.

Comment: Here's a setup for testing: http://sqlize.com/zkHmA6Ba8S

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right, this works for me:

```
SELECT child.*
FROM stack as child,
(SELECT idstack FROM stack WHERE message LIKE '%hello%') as parent
WHERE child.idstack BETWEEN parent.idstack-2 AND parent.idstack+2;
```

Comment: This might not work if there are gaps between id's, otherwise it would be a simple solution.

Comment: Assuming the id is incremental, this partly works - it doesn't return the correct id values: http://sqlize.com/i3UzLmm9u8

Comment: you would need 2 extra joins with limit of N this. Mine indeed assumes no gaps

Comment: also that should be `LIKE '%hello%'`, otherwise you are returning too  many rows

Comment: @mellamokb yeah, for his example :) Mine was only filled with a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,etc

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001648/getting-row-before-and-after-a-query for a solution for non-incremental/gapped ids

Answer (score 7):

Don't know if this is at all valid MySQL but how about

```
SELECT  t.* 
FROM    theTable t
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT id FROM theTable where message like '%hello%'
        ) id ON id.id <= t.id
ORDER BY
        ID DESC
LIMIT   3                    
UNION ALL 
SELECT  t.* 
FROM    theTable t
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT id FROM theTable where message like '%hello%'
        ) id ON id.id > t.id
ORDER BY
        ID
LIMIT   2
```

Comment: That should be `id ON t.id <= id.id` and `id ON t.id > id.id` (since the aliases are called `id`, otherwise you are comparing `t.id` to itself), then it works: http://sqlize.com/fIR8gPZ1CO

Answer (score 6):

Try this simple one (**edited**) -

```
CREATE TABLE messages(
  id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  message VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO messages VALUES 
  (1, 'One tow three'),
  (2, 'No error in this'),
  (3, 'My testing message'),
  (4, 'php module test'),
  (5, 'hello world'),
  (6, 'team spirit'),
  (7, 'puzzle game'),
  (8, 'social game'),
  (9, 'stackoverflow'),
  (10, 'stackexchange');

SET @text = 'hello world';

SELECT id, message FROM (
  SELECT m.*, @n1:=@n1 + 1 num, @n2:=IF(message = @text, @n1, @n2) pos
    FROM messages m, (SELECT @n1:=0, @n2:=0) n ORDER BY m.id
) t
WHERE @n2 >= num - 2 AND @n2 <= num + 2;

+------+--------------------+
| id   | message            |
+------+--------------------+
|    3 | My testing message |
|    4 | php module test    |
|    5 | hello world        |
|    6 | team spirit        |
|    7 | puzzle game        |
+------+--------------------+
```

N value can be specified as user variable; currently it is - '2'.

This query works with row numbers, and this guarantees that the nearest records will be returned.

Comment: Hello, I believe this is what I looking for, but I don't quite understand yet with the function of @n2. Can you explain more? The num column is for row number right? but what is the pos column?

Comment: @n2 is a variable, the IF control function sets value @n1 when the field `message` equals to @text, otherwise do nothing - just sets its value.

Comment: When I am trying it, :n2 sets to 0 for all row before the row with field message equals to :text, therefore WHERE won't work right for getting row before the row with :text.
For example the row with :text at 4th row. :n2 in 1st-3rd row will have 0 value. Then row 3 won't be selected as previous row, because pos >= num-2 -> 0 >= 3-2 is false, while it is actually a row before the 4th row. CMIIW

Comment: I have found a mistake in the query. I will try to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: I have added full script and a little changed query.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Select * from theTable
Where id >=
(Select id - variableHere from theTable where message like '%hello%')
Order by id
Limit (variableHere * 2) + 1
```

Comment: I don't believe you can [use variables in `limit` clause](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918): http://sqlize.com/3Q9z45906z

Comment: I don't know if MySql is capable of allowing variable, I just use the word variableHere loosely there. Anyway if it isn't, use your middle-tier language's data access library's parameterized query to facilitate it, pass your variable there. Don't use concatenation

Comment: if you're executing the query in a language however and the limit variable is of that language, mysql will have no problems with it.
For example:
`$limit=10;$query="Select id from temp LIMIT $limit";`

Answer (score 1):

(MS SQL Server only)

The most reliable way would be to use the row_number function that way it doesn't matter if there are gaps in the id. This will also work if there are multiple occurances of the search result and  properly return two above and below each result.

```
WITH

srt AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS int_row, [id]
    FROM theTable
),

result AS (
    SELECT int_row - 2 AS int_bottom, int_row + 2 AS int_top
    FROM theTable
        INNER JOIN srt
            ON theTable.id = srt.id
    WHERE ([message] like '%hello%')
)

SELECT theTable.[id], theTable.[message]
FROM theTable
    INNER JOIN srt
        ON theTable.id = srt.id
    INNER JOIN result
        ON srt.int_row >= result.int_bottom
        AND srt.int_row <= result.int_top
ORDER BY srt.int_row
```

Comment: oops just realized that your question was tagged mysql. This method is for SQL Server. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer using date instead of an id.
The use-case here is an on-call rotation table with one record pr week.
Due to edits the id might be out of order for the purpose intended.
Any use-case having several records pr week, pr date or other will of course have to be mended.

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| startdate| datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| person   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The query:

```
SELECT child.*
FROM rota-table as child,
 (SELECT startdate
    FROM rota-table
    WHERE YEARWEEK(startdate, 3) = YEARWEEK(now(), 3) ) as parent
WHERE
    YEARWEEK(child.startdate, 3) >= YEARWEEK(NOW() - INTERVAL 25 WEEK, 3)
    AND YEARWEEK(child.startdate, 3) <= YEARWEEK(NOW() + INTERVAL 25 WEEK, 3)
```